# Fiber preserving map that is not a bundle map

Tags: vector-bundles, fiber-bundles

I used to think every map that is fiber preserving is a bundle map in the sense of the definition below:

**Definition** Let $E\xrightarrow{\pi}M$ and $F\xrightarrow{\rho}N\ $ be vector bundles and $g:M \rightarrow N\ $ a diffeomorphism between $M$ and $N$. Then, we define that $f:E\rightarrow F\ $ is a ***bundle map that preserve fibers*** if:
$$ g\circ \pi = \rho \circ f$$

But in page 209 at [Foundations of Mechanics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201408406) a map $f:E \rightarrow F\ $ between two vector bundles such that $f\ $ is fiber preserving is defined, but there's a remark saying that $f$ ***is not necessarily a vector bundle mapping***.

**Question** How could a map be fiber preserving without being a bundle mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vector bundle mapping has to be a linear map on the fibers (the fibers are vector spaces and it has to be a linear map in the sense of vector spaces). So for a counterexample, you could take $\mathbb{R}$ thought of as the trivial bundle over a point, and any smooth map from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself  that is not linear (e.g. $x \mapsto x^2$).

Comment: (so in your notation, $\M = N = \{ \text{pt.} \}$ and, $E = F = \mathbb{R}$, and  $\pi$ and $\rho$ are the trivial map. You can shove in any $f$ and it is a map that preserves fibers, but only linear maps are a vector bundle mapping.)